# unable to add textboxes to listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi I want to add textboxes to a listbox with everyclick on the add button.
so here are my codes

```
this.ListBox1.Controls.Add(TB);//TB is the name of my TextBox and it has been defined and initialized
```

I even tried to use Addat

there are no errors but it doesnt work

Comment: if you are trying to make the list box editable you would need to write a custom control (custom list box) for this purpose...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `ListBox` you can use `ListView`, `ListView` has the ability to add custom column types

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9188/Embedding-Controls-in-a-ListView

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx

Answer (score 0):

myYou don't want to add ListBox. Rather, add an object and define a default template for this object using a TextBlock.

So you define your local Namespace

```
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
```

in the ressources you define your DataTemplate

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:type local:MyObjectType}">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThePropertyIWant}" />
 </DataTemplate>
```

And in your code you just add object of type MyObjectType to your ListBox.

But even better, you add your objects to an ObservableCollection(Of MyObjectTYpe) and you bind that collection to your listBox. So when you add objects to the collection, the display is automatically updated.